# Predicate doesn't work with two @count operators

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

This code assigns a predicate to a NSFetchRequest, for a entity that has two one to many relationships (collectionA and collectionB):

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(collectionA.@count > 0 ) OR (collectionB.@count > 0)" ]];
```

But that predicate doesn't work and all of the objects are selected. If I change that line for this other one:

```
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"collectionA.@count > 0" ]];
```

Then it works as expected and it returns all the objects with at least one item in collectionA. The same for collectionB. But as I try the OR operation to get the combination of both, then it doesn't filter any object as if the predicate was ignored.

I'm sure I am doing something wrong and perhaps two @count operators cannot be used in the same predicate. How do I have to write a predicate to get the results of objects with any item in collectionA or in collectionB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If every object has at least one object related through either `collectionA` or `collectionB`, then the predicate will always evaluate to `YES` and everything will be fetched.

Comment: Of course Dave, but that is not the case. Not all objects have relations through collectionA or collectionB. That is what I think it is a rare behavior of that predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no reason why two `@count` collection operators couldn't function in the same predicate. Sometime, you hit strange problems with `predicateWithFormat`. I would suggest creating two separate predicates and then combining them with:

```
-[NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates];
```

… creating the compound predicate directly instead of relying on the parser often resolves this type of problem.

However, you do want to make sure that you do in fact have objects that have both relationships empty because the predicate you are building will return all managed objects that have one or more objects in either relationship.

Comment: Thanks,I will use that system. But predicateWithFormat is so easy and the other form y so verbose I will keep investigating why that strange behavior does happen.

Comment: `predicateWithFormat` is a convenience method and I use it 90% of the time but it does have to parse and sometimes it does seems to fail and hand created predicates necessary.